# How to set proxy on constructor function

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, es6-proxy

I have a constructor function like this:

```
function a(p){
this.k=12;
this.f = p;
this.t = function(){};
}
```

Now let say i create a object with this function:

```
let obj = new a("tf");
```

I can always do this to check if a new property assigned to object:

```
obj = new Proxy(obj,{set:()=>{console.log("new property assigned!");return true;}})
//Now if i were to say
obj.property1 = 12
//It will log out "new property assigned!"
```

But the problem is, that i have to do this for every new object i create with this constructor function.
So what i want to do is whenever i create a new object like this:

```
let newObj = new a();
```

I want to set my proxy automatically.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Use a factory function around the constructor and proxy, and call that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a factory function in which you create a new instance of your object while also adds a Proxy to the newly created instance.

```
function proxyFactory(Class, ...args) {
  const instance = new Class(...args);
  return new Proxy(instance, {
    set: () => {
      console.log("new property assigned!");
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

And then call the factory function with the class and the arguments you want to apply.

```
let newObj = proxyFactory(a, "tf");
```

Comment: thanks it works but you should return the new Proxy

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Made the adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a proxy around class, intercept `construct` calls, and return a proxy with `set` trap.

```js
const A = new Proxy(a, {
  construct(target, args) {
    return new Proxy(new target(...args), {
      set() {
        console.log('new property assigned');
        return true
      }
    })
  }
})

const inst = new A('tf')

inst.property = true

function a(p) {
  this.k = 12;
  this.f = p;
  this.t = function() {};
}
```

Comment: I didn't know the construct method until today, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that wraps around your class. E.g.

```js
const proxyify = (Class, ...args) => {
   return new Proxy(new Class(...args), {
        set: () => {
            console.log('set');
            return true;
        }
   });
}
```

Usage would then be

```js
function Dog() {
    this.type = "Dog";
}

const ProxiedDog = proxify(Dog);
```

Comment: OP wants to wrap the instances in proxies, not the class itself.